# Making a calendar editable to anyone?

Tags: calendar

I am trying to make a webpage that looks like the Google Calendar and allows anyone to add/edit/delete any event, working like a notice board.

For now I am using a customized UI to show all the events in my Google Calendar and it works perfectly. But I can't find out how to let anyone access my Google Calendar to post, edit or delete events. I tried AuthSub but it requires user to enter the username and password I provide. I don't want them to enter anything, neither their own Google Accounts nor the public Google Account I provide, except events. Is there any good and free choice to do that?

Comment: I'm looking to this too... Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not completely tied to Google Calendar, you could have a look at [Calagator](http://code.google.com/p/calagator/). Originally written specifically for the Portland tech community, it can be adapted fairly easily - my friend did up [VanCal.org](http://vancal.org/), which does a similar function. In addition to add / delete / edit, you can import and export events from Google Calendar, iCal, etc.